# How to convert Fluent NHibernate mapping to NHibernate Built-in Code Based Mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have two classes from example using Fluent NHibernate mapping. Fluent NHibernate mapping is commented and I´m  trying to make Code Based Mapping, but still appears ArgumentNullException "Value cannot be null.". How to make it right?

```
//Fluent NHIbernate mapping for table LocalizationEntry
//public class LocalizationEntryMapping : ClassMap<LocalizationEntry>
//{
//    public LocalizationEntryMapping()
//    {
//        Cache.ReadWrite();
//        CompositeId()
//            .ComponentCompositeIdentifier(x => x.Id)
//            .KeyProperty(x => x.Id.Culture)
//            .KeyProperty(x => x.Id.EntityId)
//            .KeyProperty(x => x.Id.Property)
//            .KeyProperty(x => x.Id.Type);
//        Map(x => x.Message);
//    }
//}
public class LocalizationEntryId
{
    public virtual string Culture { get; set; }
    public virtual string Type { get; set; }
    public virtual string Property { get; set; }
    public virtual string EntityId { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            LocalizationEntryId other = obj as LocalizationEntryId;
            if (other != null)
            {
                return this.Type      == other.Type &&
                        this.Property == other.Property &&
                        this.EntityId == other.EntityId &&
                        this.Culture  == other.Culture;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class LocalizationEntry : IDomainMapper
{
    public virtual LocalizationEntryId Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Message { get; set; }

    public virtual void Map(ModelMapper mapper)
    {
        mapper.Class<LocalizationEntry>(m =>
        {                
            m.ComposedId( t =>
            {
                t.Property(g => g.Id.Culture, c =>
                {
                    c.NotNullable(true);
                    c.Length(10);
                });
                t.Property(g => g.Id.EntityId, c =>
                {
                    c.NotNullable(true);
                });
                t.Property(g => g.Id.Property, c =>
                {
                    c.NotNullable(true);
                    c.Length(100);
                });
                t.Property(g => g.Id.Type, c =>
                {
                    c.NotNullable(true);
                    c.Length(100);
                });
            });

            m.Property(t => t.Message, c =>
            {
                c.NotNullable(true);
                c.Length(400);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

//////////// EDIT ////////////////
I found the solution already. Mapping should be done this way:

```
public virtual void Map(ModelMapper mapper)
        {
            mapper.Class<LocalizationEntry>(m =>
            {
                m.ComponentAsId(x => x.Id, n =>
                {
                    n.Property(x => x.Culture);
                    n.Property(x => x.EntityId);
                    n.Property(x => x.Property);
                    n.Property(x => x.Type);
                });

                m.Property(t => t.Message, c =>
                {
                    c.NotNullable(true);
                    c.Length(400);
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `ClassMapping<T>`?

Comment: If you found the solution, post it yourself as an answer and accept it. That way it's way clearer than an edit in the very same question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution already. Mapping should be done this way:

```
public virtual void Map(ModelMapper mapper)
    {
        mapper.Class<LocalizationEntry>(m =>
        {
            m.ComponentAsId(x => x.Id, n =>
            {
                n.Property(x => x.Culture);
                n.Property(x => x.EntityId);
                n.Property(x => x.Property);
                n.Property(x => x.Type);
            });

            m.Property(t => t.Message, c =>
            {
                c.NotNullable(true);
                c.Length(400);
            });
        });
    }
```